# how to use Xquery and FLOWR to iterate and return each result?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xquery, basex

I'm looking to iterate a [sample](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml) bookstore returning each book as a result.  How is this accomplished with XQuery and FLOWR?

My best attempt so far:

```
thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$ basex each.xq 
<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web" cover="paperback">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$ cat each.xq 
let $db := db:open("com.w3schools.books")
for $item in $db
return $item/bookstore/book
thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$
```

Only I'd "kinda" like each result differentiated a bit more.  Can I chain or pipe results from one Xquery to another perhaps?  The output I would want would be more like serializing each book to an xml file.

the data:

```
thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$ basex all.xq 
<bookstore>
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="children">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <author>Per Bothner</author>
    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
    <author>James Linn</author>
    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web" cover="paperback">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$ cat all.xq 
let $db := db:open("com.w3schools.books")
return $db
thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$
```

Certainly, possible to return a single result:

```
thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$ basex singleBook.xq 
<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$ cat singleBook.xq 
let $db := db:open("com.w3schools.books")
for $x in $db
return $x/bookstore/book[1]
thufir@dur:~/basex/w3schools$
```

However, that's just a single book.  How would I iterate through returning each book?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your desired output? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: If you `return $x/bookstore/book` instead of `return $x/bookstore/book[1]` you return all `book` elements obviously instead of only the first. Seems too obvious so I am not sure what you are looking for. The whole idea of "iterating" in the context of a declarative language is perhaps not the best objective to start with when using XQuery.

Comment: I don't know how to describe the desired output @JackFleeting but I guess what I want is book #1, then book #2, etc.  But, *individually* not as a single result...

Comment: What kind of result type do you expect, if you select several `book` elements then the result is a sequence of `book` elements e.g. `element(book)*` in that XPath/XQuery sequence types type system. It doesn't really matter whether for the type whether you use `db:open('db-name')/bookstore/book` or `for $doc in db:open('db-name'), $store in $doc/bookstore, $book in $store/book return $book`, the result is a sequence of `book` elements.

Comment: if sequence means a sequence of distinct items @MartinHonnen, then it's that sequence which I'm after.  I suppose it's already a sequence of book items.  I'm thinking of an analog to an array, List or other collection.

Comment: It is a sequence of book element nodes and that is the XDM type of a list of element nodes. Granted, in XQuery 3.1 you could also create an array of book element nodes (`array { db:open('db-name')/bookstore/book }`) but I doubt there is a better integration into APIs or host languages if you make it an array instead of a sequence. Are you trying to process the XQuery result with a certain API where your current code doesn't allow you to access each item in the result sequence?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's not clear exactly how you want the output, try something like this (I made up some structure) - it may get you close to your ultimate destination...

```
for $x in $db/book
return 
(<book-info>
{$x/title/text()}, {$x/author[1]/text()}
</book-info>,'&#10;')
```

Output:

```
<book-info>
Everyday Italian, Giada De Laurentiis
</book-info>


<book-info>
Harry Potter, J K. Rowling
</book-info>


<book-info>
XQuery Kick Start, James McGovern
</book-info>


<book-info>
Learning XML, Erik T. Ray
</book-info>
```

Comment: I'm going to leave open for a bit, but that's pretty much what I'm looking for.  Probably, as Martin said, I'm more thinking imperative than declarative.